# How to stop html5 video from playing when out of viewport?

Tags: html, video, skrollr

I'm facing this problem with skrollr: everything goes fine, then when adding a video, it continues playing if out of viewport, even if the div has a display:none declaration. I tried searching here and Google but couldn't find anything and at this point I'm really lost.

For reference, this is the code I'm using:

```
<div id="seventh" class="view" data-0="display:none;top:0%;" data-27000="display:block;opacity:0;" data-29000="opacity:1;" data-32000="opacity:0;" >

<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="1223" height="611" poster="img/poster.jpg" data-setup="{}">
<source src="videos/vid.webm" type='video/webm' />
<source src="videos/vid.mp4" type='video/mp4' />

</video>

</div>
```

any help on how to achieve this really appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
skrollr.init({
    render: function(data) {
        //get current element opacity and position then play or pause the video
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ybP6b/ for a working example